# Challenges with Stripe integration in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, async-await, stripe-payments

- I haven't been able to find any real solid tutorials / examples of integrating payment into a Meteor app, just what's available using Nodes.JS with Express
- [Stripe guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment) I'm trying (and failing) to follow / integrate into my app
- This is a [possible solution](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-methods-return-values-via-promise-async/42060), **but I could use help dissecting it for Stripe integration following the guide listed above**
- Are there any simple guides that do not include mrgalaxy:stripe as their solution
- That package hasn't been updated since 2016 and I'd really prefer more up to date dependencies
- I'm specifically stuck on await / async / promises and could use some help with the checkout portion
- If I need to paste code I will, but mainly I'm looking for something more recent that can help me integrate a simple checkout process

Thanks!

Comment: Requests for recommendations of off-site resource like guides and packages are off topic here. If you have a *specific problem* with your current implementation, give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Meteor has good compatibility with `npm` packages, so there shouldn't be anything necessary here. It looks like you've also asked over in the Meteor forums so you may get a better & more specific answer there.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated Stripe into my Meteor app. As previously stated you can use the `stripe` npm on the server side.

```
meteor npm install stripe
```

I tend to have a file somewhere in my project that I initialize my stripe from. eg. `/imports/stripe.js`:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import Stripe from 'stripe'

const stripe = new Stripe(Meteor.settings.Stripe.secretKey, {
  maxNetworkRetries: 2,
})
export default stripe
```

Then whenever I need to use the stripe api from my project I can just do:

```
import stripe from '/imports/stripe'
```

And to take advantage of checkout.js or other front end integration for the client side if you wish. They tend to be as easy as dropping `<script>` tag into your project `index.html`

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#redirect-checkout